# Visual Studio 2013 ASP.NET MVC Template intellisense doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resharper, intellisense

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2013 (with resharper 8.1) - ASP.NET MVC default template.

Intellisense was work, but it stopped one moment and I'm dying in agony.

When I open Visual Studio 2012 asp.net internet application template in VS2013 - it's everything OK.
Screenshoots: (left side - vs2013 mvc template, right side - vs 2012 mvc template)

[image]
[image]

I deleted .suo file, did reset visual studio settings, "repair" the Visual studio, suspend resharper, delete cache and still nothing. Doesn't matter how many new projects I create.

What should i try now? :(

**EDIT:**

I Opened template from vs2013 in vs 2012 but it's still the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

Add a extension to resharper "Resharper.ExternalAnnotations".

Restart Resharper.

Done :)

Comment: Just to clarify - this ReSharper extension is bundled with ReSharper 8, and contains all of the annotations that enable such functionality. It was packaged as an extension so that it could be updated out-of-band with releases for ReSharper, so you can just update the extension and get new annotations - such as updates to support a newer version of MVC. The problem is, it can be uninstalled, and cause issues! Later versions of ReSharper follow a similar mechanism, but the extension is hidden, and updated automatically in the background.